# Get all children's with document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `Intersection Observer` to make the content load when a insersection point is defined. I'm using it with a `bootstrap 4 carousel`, the intersection point is in the `h1`. The problem is that the script only catch the first `h1`, if the carousel goes to the second `h1` when the user make the intersection on it, the slider don't appear, because the added `class` that show the content with an `animation` is applied only in the first `div h1` parent content. So, I want to get all the `h1`, not only the first one. I tried to stop the carousel for intersection forever with the first `h1`, but i can't get to start it again when it displayed finally with the `animation`. You can see an example [here](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html), in the middle of the page.

```
// Instantiate a new Intersection Observer
let observer5 = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry5);
let test = document.querySelector('#carouselExampleControls3');


let element5 = document.querySelector(".test-h1");
observer5.observe(element5);

function onEntry5(entry5) {

  if (entry5[0].isIntersecting) {
    test.classList.add("active");

  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls3" class="carousel slide test-slider" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active carousel-item-left">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/_MG_6501-copia.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="padding-right: 200px;padding-bottom: 200px;border: 0px; ">
      <h1 class="test-h1" style="z-index: 1000000;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #c33e69;
    font-size: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 70px;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 363px;">ESTA ES MI SEGUNDA CASA</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>

<div class="carousel-item carousel-item-next carousel-item-left">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="banner col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mx-auto">
            <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="https://www.eharmony.co.uk/dating-advice/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/profilephotos.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="padding-right: 200px;padding-bottom: 200px;border: 0px; ">
      <h1 class="test-h1" style="     z-index: 1000000;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #c33e69;
    font-size: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 70px;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 363px;">ESTA ES MI SEGUNDA CASA</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    </div>

</div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
#carouselExampleControls3 {opacity: 0; transition: 1.5s opacity;}
#carouselExampleControls3.active {opacity: 1;  cursor: pointer;
  animation: zoomin 1.5s alternate infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;}
```

Comment: on a side note, is that your site, the design is good !.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to `document.querySelectorAll()`! Grab all elements that match the query then use a `forEach` loop to apply whatever functionality you want.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

For your use case I would do something like this:

```js
const carousels = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper-carousel-thingy');

if (carousels) {
  carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
    const trigger = carousel.querySelector('.some-inner-trigger-element');
    trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      carousel.classList.add('active');
    });
    trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      carousel.classList.remove('active');
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.wrapper-carousel-thingy {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper-carousel-thingy.active {
  border-color: red; /* border color change just an example of how you can update the parent element based on hover of interior element */
}
.some-inner-trigger-element:hover {
  background: yellow; /* just to emphasize which element is the trigger */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-carousel-thingy class-that-makes-me-unique"> <!-- as many of these as you want -->
  <div class="whatever-in-between">
    <h1 class="some-inner-trigger-element">I am the trigger</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u insert it in the JS code that I provided in the question to make it work? I don't know where and how I need to insert it. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, let me know if you follow the example I gave.

Comment: I'm a newbie with JS, sorry.